# Django - reverse foreignkey select_related

Tags: django, foreign-keys

So, similar questions have been asked before, but I have been unable to find a conclusive answer.

Given the following models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class ChildA(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent')

class ChildB(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent')
```

How can I get all the children of a given parent? Select related only goes forwards, so that won't work as far as I can tell. Prefetch related seems to only operate when there is an actual field reference in the parent (ie, if the parent has a field that is a m2m with a child) so I don't see how that would work.

I'm sure this is something I've just overlooked in the docs, given how rudimentary and common this sort of problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `select_related` or `prefetch_related`. To get all the children of a parent with your structure, you will always need to do two queries:

```
my_children = list(my_parent.childa_set.all()) + list(my_parent.childb_set.all())
```

Comment: So for N children, I will always need at least N queries? Ok. What is the parent.childa_set syntax you are using?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Ah, fantastic,thanks. So it's basically a shorthand for Child.objects.filter(parent=myparent)